# Excel - dynamically placing boolean based on multiple criteria

Tags: excel, excel-2010

First off let me say thanks and sorry for potential poor formatting. I tried to make it as straightforward as possible, but I am not sure how to insert a table into this box.

I have the following two columns side by side in Excel, in columns A and B.

```
1   INIT
2   INIT
3   INIT
4   INIT
4   UNWIND
3   INIT
5   INIT
1   UNWIND
```

In column C, I would like to place a 1 if the numbers in the first columns are the same AND those numbers have both an INIT and the UNWIND. Thus the final solution would look like this:

```
1   INIT      1
2   INIT      0
3   INIT      0
4   INIT      1
4   UNWIND    1
3   INIT      0
5   INIT      0
1   UNWIND    1
```

Note in the example above, even though 3 showed up in column A twice, a zero was placed in column C because the second "3" had "INIT" in column B, not "UNWIND".

I was thinking of using a combination of If statements with Match, etc., but I'm not sure how to dynamically complete the task, since the range over which you are searching will change (all rows of the column, excluding the row you are currently in). In this example, for row 1, you would simply search all rows below it. However, for row 2, you would want to search the row above it, and all those that follow, and so on.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: So the question is give me the code?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to test to see if any number in column A has both an "INIT" and "UNWIND" value.  The simplest solution here is [COUNTIFS](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/countifs-function-HA102753238.aspx?CTT=5&origin=HA102753077) with an AND.

```
=AND(COUNTIF(A:A,A1)=2,COUNTIFS(A:A,A1,B:B,"INIT")=1,COUNTIFS(A:A,A1,B:B,"UNWIND")=1)
```

Of course, note that the formula I provided will count ALL of the columns, and requires exactly two matching rows with one INIT and one UNWIND.  And it'll return a boolean true or false rather than a 1 or 0, but you should be able to cast a boolean to whatever value easy enough.

(And if possible, use Tables post Excel 2007.  They make the formula FAR easier to read.)

Answer (score 0):

Alternate formula:

```
=--AND(COUNTIFS(A:A,A1,B:B,{"INIT","UNWIND"}))
```